# Problems with jQuery Cycle + Caroufredsel

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle, caroufredsel

I have created a jQuery Cycle/Maximage2 gallery, while using caroufredsel for the carousel thumbnail navigation, but caroufredsel isn't firing until you resize the browser window for some reason. I have tried wrapping cycle in

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

and wrapping caroufredsel in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

to see if that would help but still no change.

JS Fiddle below: (resize the internal browser to see it fire).

http://jsfiddle.net/AZgjA/2/

Comment: I cannot replicate this, it works the same when I resize... which browser are you using?

Comment: Tried in FF/Chrome/Safari on Mac.

Comment: Have the exact same issue on chromium and firefox. It happens only if I adjust the width to something else, like '50%'. Did you find any solution?